# malloc: *** error for object: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Tags: c++, c, pointers, malloc, huffman-code

Can someone help me figure out where I'm getting this error. I know it's probably a double deletion or something like this. For the background this is an implementation of the huffman's tree as you can easily realize on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding).

[CharCountNode class implementation](http://pastebin.com/6CM9eman)

```
int main()
{
  ifstream input;
  input.open("input.txt");

  MinPriorityQueue<CharCountNode> heap;
  map<char, int> m;

  while(input.good())
    m[input.get()] += 1;

  for( map<char, int>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it )
    heap.enqueue(CharCountNode(it->first, it->second));


  while(heap.getSize() > 1)
  {
    CharCountNode a, b, parent;

    a = heap.dequeue();
    b = heap.dequeue();
    parent = CharCountNode('*', a.getCount() + b.getCount());

    parent.left = &a;
    parent.right = &b;

    heap.enqueue(parent);
  }
}
```

Comment: set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug.

Comment: Apply `valgrind` and fix the *very first* thing it complains about.  Repeat until program works correctly.

Comment: As of the time of this post: valgrind doesn't work with Mac OS X 10.10.

Comment: @CGTheLegend Use a VM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with this code:

```
parent.left = &a;
parent.right = &b;
```

This is getting pointers to local variables, which will be reinitialized next time around the loop. `CharCountNode` will eventually try to `delete` these objects, but they haven't been allocated by new.

You need to make `left` and `right` point to objects allocated on the heap, as that is what `CharCountNode` is expecting. Something like:

```
parent.left = new CharCountNode(a);
parent.right = new CharCountNode(b);
```