# No viable conversion from 'Class *' to 'Class' C++

Tags: c++, class, reference

I feel like this should be simple but for whatever reason I can't get it to work.

I'm trying to create an instance of a class that can be passed into and edited directly by other functions.

For example:

```
main()
{
    ClassFoo foo = new ClassFoo();
    someFunction(foo);
}

void someFunction(ClassFoo& f)
{
    f.add("bar");
}
```

The problem is, when compiling, I end up with this error.

```
no viable conversion from 'ClassFoo *' to 'ClassFoo'
    ClassFoo foo = new ClassFoo();
             ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It also says that other candidate constructors are not viable, however in my `ClassFoo` class I do have a constructor that looks like this:

```
ClassFoo::ClassFoo()
{}
```

So how would I be able to accomplish editing the `ClassFoo` variable in functions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

C++ is not Java (or C# I suppose). You should never use the `new` keyword unless you [know that you need to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679571/when-to-use-new-and-when-not-to-in-c). And it returns a pointer to the newly created class, hence the error you get. Likely, the following would be sufficient:

```
Class foo;
someFunction(foo);
```

For a default constructed object, you shouldn't include the `()` if you're not using `new`, as this does something completely different (see [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse))

Comment: The only time when you probably need to use `new` in modern C++ is when specifying custom deleters for smart pointers. +1

Comment: Thank you for this. Any idea why when exiting the program (just returning 0 in main), it says that `pointer being freed was not allocated`?

Comment: @Alex That implies somewhere you have a `delete` call that's trying to delete something that was not allocated with `new`. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22824802/malloc-error-for-object-pointer-being-freed-was-not-allocated-set-a-br . But like how `new` shouldn't show up unless you really know you need it, neither should `delete`.

Comment: `Class foo();` would be a function declaration. `Class foo{};` would more closely match what you are saying (although if the class were an aggregate then the `{}` would be significant)

Answer (score 6):

You're probably used to C# or similar sintax..

However, in C++, there are big differences between these lines:

```
ClassFoo foo; //local variable at stack
ClassFoo *foo = new ClassFoo(); //local pointer to some memory at heap which is structured like ClassFoo
```

You probably wanted first line just to create local object.
There are numerous tutorials that describe difference between heap and stack.. so check them out